# Scatter plot between two predictors X1 and X2

Tags: r

Given the following scatter plot between two predictors X1 and X2:

[image: Plot Graph]

Is there a way to get the number of parameters of a linear model like that?

```
model <- lm(Y~X1+X2)
```

I would like to get the number 3 somehow (intercept + X1 + X2). I looked for something like this in the structures that lm, summary(model) and anova(model) return, but I didn't figure it out. 
In case I don't get an answer, I'll stick on `dim(model.matrix(model))[2]` Thank you

I was thinking that X1 and X2 are correlated. Collinearity will reduce the accuracy of the estimates of the regression coefficients

Maybe the The importance of either X1 or X2 variable may be masked due to the presence of collinearity?

Though they both could be correct

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it doesn't belong here. You could try asking on stats.stackexchange, but it's usually good when asking for homework help to not just post the question and ask for the answer, but to discuss your thoughts so far, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stats homework help. Not on-topic here. Not a good question for stats.stackexchange.

Comment: I edited it. Does this look better. Thank you so much for letting me know.

Comment: your question is still a little confusing. `length(coef(model))` will give you the number of parameters.

Comment: The answer is both questions are correct. Just figured it out. 

Yes.  X1 and X2 are correlated. Collinearity will reduce the accuracy of the estimates of the regression coefficients.

   
Yes. The importance of either X1 or X2 variable may be masked due to the presence of collinearity.

Answer (score 0):

In a linear model to get the 2nd beta, you need to have your y variable predicted/explained by at least 2 independent variables. If you are predicting 1 variable explained by only 1 variable, your linear model will only produce 1 beta.